# How to remap xml so that only repetitive values in nodes are displayed

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml structure:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nodes>
<Node>
    <a>xxx</a>
    <b>adad</b>
    <c>yyy</c>
    <d>ddwr</d>
    <e>awe</e>
</Node>
<Node>
    <a>xxx</a>
    <b>adaddad</b>
    <c>yyy</c>
    <d>kodoska</d>
    <e>lkadkda</e>
</Node>
<Node>
    <a>xxx</a>
    <b>adase</b>
    <c>yyy</c>
    <d>kodoa.smdkadska</d>
    <e>lkadddadaadsasdkda</e>
</Node>
</nodes>
```

I would like to map with xslt so that only nodes with nodes with the same values are displayed. So I expect something like this out:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Node>
<a>xxx</a>
<c>yyy</c>
</Node>
```

Comment: Does your processor support XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a regular structure (all `Node` elements having the same child nodes), you could do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="node-by-name" match="Node/*" use="name()" />

<xsl:template match="/nodes">
    <Node>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Node[1]/*[not(. != key('node-by-name', name()))]"/>
    </Node>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, for your response, I am very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are doing two things: deduplicating element's name, testing if all of them have equal values.

This stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:key name="kElement-By-Name" match="Node/*" use="name()"/>
    <xsl:template match="nodes">
        <Node>
            <xsl:for-each 
              select="Node/*[
                generate-id()=generate-id(key('kElement-By-Name',name())[1])
              ]">
                <xsl:copy-of select="(.)[not(. != key('kElement-By-Name',name()))]"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Node>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<Node>
  <a>xxx</a>
  <c>yyy</c>
</Node>
```

**Do note**: grouping for deduplication, node set comparison are existencial (so, all are the same if there is no one wich is different)

Comment: Thank you very much, for your response, I am very grateful.